# How to align hr with div below it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to align an hr to a div below it. This is the css:

```
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:80%;
}
```

the line is currently not aligned with the div#main it is too much to the left:

```
<hr class="line">
<div id="main" class="container border">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I align this with the div, get the same width and at the same time make it responsive?

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/bertie2017/pen/RYOZwL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess here is what you want: [codepen](https://codepen.io/gholizadeh/pen/dqLVZa)
you can also remove hr margin

```
<div>
<hr class="line container">
<div id="main" class="container border">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5"><label for="title">Title</label><input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title placeholder" name="title" value=""><label for="temp">Temperature</label><span id="tempArea" class="row"><span class="col-lg-4"><input type="radio" id="c" class="spaceradio" value="metric" checked=""><label for="c" class="radios">℃</label></span>
            <span
             class="col-lg-4"><input type="radio" id="f" class="spaceradio" value="imperial"><label for="f" class="radios">℉</label></span>
                </span><br><label for="temp">Wind</label><span id="windArea" class="row"><span class="col-lg-4"><input type="radio" id="n" class="spaceradio" value="true"><label for="n" class="radios">On</label></span><span class="col-lg-4"><input type="radio" id="o" class="spaceradio" value="false" checked=""><label for="o" class="radios">Off</label></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="border-right col-lg-6"><img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/02d.png"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6"><br>
                        <h2>65.34<label>℉</label></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.line {
    border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Good work, how did you come to add the padding? Why does this make the line the same width?

Comment: container class has different media queries so I used the same class. but it contains 15px padding. when you put a row (contains -15px padding) in container it makes divisions inside row same width with container.

Answer (score 0):

Changed styles of hr to margin: 1 auto; But if only want to make it center and no need of margin at top , margin: auto is enough. Hope you got the answer

Answer (score -1):

I changed this line from margin: 1em 0; to margin: 1 0;
Now hr is in center.

and width:95%;

Comment: forgot to mention it has to have to same width as the div.

Comment: Try adding the class "container" to the "hr" tag so it have similar style that main div.

Comment: `margin: 1 0` is invalid CSS, so what you really did is just change the `hr`'s margin back to the user agent default because the browser isn't applying your new style at all. Margins have to have units on them, unless you're using `auto`.